# Missing stc++.lib; how to build from source?

Tags: c++, open-source

I'm attempting to build ffmpeg on Windows with support for libmfx (QuickSync for windows) using the MSVC toolchain. The libmfx PC file references stdc++.lib, but this library is not in the media SDK. Though I've found source repositories for several versions, I haven't found any instructions for building this LIB file from source. Can someone direct me to the relevant instructions?

Comment: I believe you can use vcpkg to build a ffmpeg library that can be used with msvc. There is a port: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/ffmpeg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/ffmpeg)

Comment: I did try that but this implementation of MSVC does not have an option for libmfx.